# Using SVG in a JSON file as a file instead of code

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm working on a ReactJS app and I have some custom-made icons in SVG format so I can style them as needed for hover, themes, etc.

I can't simply put the SVG code in the main Component, it has to be injected from a JSON file. Mainly because it will display as a repeater depending on how many I need.

My code works perfectly this way:

```
{userRole.map((role, index) => (
    <div id={role.id} key={role.id}>
        <div>
            {role.name}
            <div className="role-icon">
                {role.icon}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
))}

//JSON FILE CODE

exports.userRoles = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Administrator',
        icon: <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 116.35 94.22"><title>super-admin</title><path d="M78.25,53.94,66.58,86.6H87.11V64.07a10,10,0,0,0-6.82-9.5Zm0,0" transform="translate(-5.82 -16.67)"/><path d="M64,37A10.19,10.19,0,1,0,53.81,26.85,10.2,10.2,0,0,0,64,37Zm0,0" transform="translate(-5.82 -16.67)"/><path d="M47.71,54.57a10,10,0,0,0-6.82,9.5V86.6H61.42L49.75,53.94Zm0,0" transform="translate(-5.82 -16.67)"/><path d="M118,91.49H10A4.22,4.22,0,0,0,5.82,95.7v11A4.21,4.21,0,0,0,10,110.88H118a4.21,4.21,0,0,0,4.22-4.21v-11A4.22,4.22,0,0,0,118,91.49Zm0,0" transform="translate(-5.82 -16.67)"/><path d="M103.58,26.34a14.82,14.82,0,0,0-11-4.92H78.7a15.51,15.51,0,0,1,1,5.43,15.67,15.67,0,0,1-31.34,0,15.51,15.51,0,0,1,1-5.43H35.44A14.8,14.8,0,0,0,20.73,37.84L26,86.6H35.4V64.07A15.5,15.5,0,0,1,46,49.35l4.62-1.42A2.74,2.74,0,0,1,54,49.62L64,74.8,74,49.62a2.74,2.74,0,0,1,3.38-1.69L82,49.35A15.5,15.5,0,0,1,92.6,64.07V86.6H102l5.31-48.76a14.84,14.84,0,0,0-3.69-11.5Zm-35.91,22-2.14,3.22,1,8.44-2,5.23a.59.59,0,0,1-1.12,0l-2-5.23,1-8.44-2.14-3.22a1.85,1.85,0,0,1,.24-2.18,1.94,1.94,0,0,1,1.43-.6h4a1.94,1.94,0,0,1,1.43.6,1.85,1.85,0,0,1,.24,2.18Zm0,0" transform="translate(-5.82 -16.67)"/></svg>,
    },
    {
        id='2',
        name='user',
        icon= '<svg>...</svg> ',
    },
    {
        id='3',
        name='tester',
        icon= '<svg>...</svg> ',
    }
    ... you get the idea
];
```

Now, what I am trying to accomplish is putting all that svg code in their respective files and use it in the JSON. Perhaps something like this

```
exports.userRoles = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Administrator',
        icon: admin.svg,
    },
    {
        id='2',
        name='user',
        icon= user.svg,
    },
    {
        id='3',
        name='tester',
        icon= tester.svg',
    }
    ... you get the idea
];
```

p.s.. I am aware I can use svg inside an `<img src={icon} />` However, I need to preserve the SVG properties so I can style it accordingly. So it can't be used as an image

How can I do this? Save my SVG code in their respective files, use the file and path name in the JSON line, so I can call it in my JSX code and render it as SVG HTML code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a slightly different approach. You could create a component for each svg (I have shown you an example below). Then, in your mapping function, you can chose which component to display depending on the value set in your JSON.

**SVG component:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class UserIcon extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1" width="128" height="128">
                <g>
                    <path fill={this.props.fill} d="M109.3 55.5h-36l12-12a29.5 29.5 0 0 0-49.6 12h-17A46 46 0 0 1 97 31.8l12.3-12.3v36zm-90.5 17h36l-12 12a29.5 29.5 0 0 0 49.5-12h17A46 46 0 0 1 31 96.2l-12.4 12.3v-36z"/>
                    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 64 64" to="360 64 64" dur="1280ms" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        )
    }
}

UserIcon.defaultProps = {  
    "fill": "#ffffff88"  
}
```

**Chosing the right icon**

```
renderIcon(icon){
    if(icon == 'user'){
        return <UserIcon>
    }else if(icon == 'admin'){
        return <AdminIcon>
    }
    // etc.
}

{userRole.map((role, index) => (
    <div id={role.id} key={role.id}>
        <div>
            {role.name}
            <div className="role-icon">
                {this.renderIcon(role.icon)}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
))}
```

Comment: I recommend reading this blog post for more info on creating SVG components: https://css-tricks.com/creating-svg-icon-system-react/

Comment: Great work, and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the link too

Comment: @LOTUSMS Glad it helped. I really like this approach as it is very React-like

Answer (score 0):

Do you use webpack ? You can achive it with `svg-inline-loader` [https://github.com/webpack-contrib/svg-inline-loader]